# c# winform , How to fitch or how to get usersId from Group

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I'am displaying how many patients have a specific diseases and grouping by age. I'am Calculating their age by using CalculateAge function
Let say poeple at age 40 are 10 people who have the specifik diseases
and poeple at 30 age are so many... and poeaple at age 50 are so many .... e.t.c. You get the idea.
My code works fine with that. But How can I get their Id? I mean How can I display who are those poeple like their name by cell Clicking on datagridview
How can fitch or get Those peoples Id's ? By some how I have to collect them i array and use them inside datagridview ClickEvent? I have problem with next step to display every patients 
FirstName and last name when I click datagridview row. 
This is my code to display by group age and works fine

```
    var result = await(from u in db.Patient
                        join a in db.Analys on u.PatientId equals a.PatientId
                        where a.diseaseId == diseasId
                        select u.DOB).Distinct().ToListAsync();
                        var data = result
                        .GroupBy(x => CalculateAge(x.ToString()))

                                     .Select(grp => new
                                     {
                                         Age = grp.Key,
                                         Amount = grp.Count()
                                     }).ToList();


                        dgvResult.DataSource = data;
```

But then Here I want to display in detail those poeple

```
private void dgvResult_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

            if (e.RowIndex > -1)
            {

                     // Here I can only catch age but this mean all patients whtin this age and will not be correct
                    int age =  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
}
```

I hope you get the Idea, and please help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure but if you do like this, what do you get?

```
    int[] PatiendIds;
//then in your select new 
    select new {u.DOB, u.PatientId}).Distinct().ToListAsync();
     PatiendIds = result.Select(x => x.u.PatientId).ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but this givs me all Patients ids in datagridView. Let say first row is patients with age 40 , second row is with age 30 and so on. Then When I Click first row who group of age 40, then I want to get their patient ids. I mean I want only for selected rows patientId, the yma be many so I want to ge ttheir id. Thank you again